# Sharing psycopg2 / libpq connections across processes

Tags: python, linux, sockets, multiprocessing, psycopg2

According to [`psycopg2` docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#thread-and-process-safety):

> `libpq` connections [shouldn’t be used by a forked processes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNECT), so when using a module such as `multiprocessing` or a forking web deploy method such as FastCGI make sure to create the connections *after* the fork.

Following [the link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNECT) from that document leads to:

> On Unix, forking a process with open `libpq` connections can lead to unpredictable results because the parent and child processes share the same sockets and operating system resources. For this reason, such usage is not recommended, though doing an exec from the child process to load a new executable is safe.

But [it seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014055/how-is-socket-connection-being-handled-in-a-forked-process) there's no inherent problem with forking processes with open sockets. So what's the reason for `psycopg2`'s warning against forking when connections are open?

The reason for my question is that I saw a (presumably successful) [multiprocessing approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7556042/336527) that opened a connection right before forking.

Perhaps it is safe to fork open connections under some restrictions (e.g., only one process actually ever uses the connection, etc.)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your surmise is basically correct: there is no issue with a connection being opened before a fork as long as you don't attempt to use it in more than one process.

<del>That being said, I think you misunderstood the "multiprocessing approach" link you provided. It actually demonstrates a separate connection being opened in each child. (There is a connection opened by the parent before forking, but it's not being used in any child.)</del>

<del>The improvement given by the answer there (versus the code in the question) was to refactor so that -- rather than opening a new connection for each task in the queue -- each child process opened a single connection and then shared it across multiple tasks executed within the same child (i.e. the connection is passed as an argument to the Task processor).</del>

**Edit**:
As a general practice, one should prefer creating a connection within the process that is using it. In the answer cited, a connection was being created in the parent before forking, then used in the child. This does work fine, but leaves each "child connection" open in the parent as well, which is at best a waste of resources and also a potential cause of bugs.

Comment: So it's not too bad to share connections across processes then - as long as one is careful? Regarding the multiprocessing approach link: the connection is created in `__init__` method of a subclass of `multiprocessing.Process`. And `__init__` [seems to only run in the master process](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17220739/336527), which means the connection is created in the master, not child, process.

Comment: Doh! You're right. My apologies. And in fact therefore it demonstrates exactly the point you were asking about: It's fine to open the connection in one process, then fork and use it in the child, as long as you're not also using it in the parent -- or another child. (It would be better as a general practice to not open the connection until after the fork though. Consider that the parent has N + 1 connections open -- for N children -- but is only using the 1.)