# Why is multiprocessing.Pool closing/not sharing SQL connections across processes?

Tags: python, postgresql, connection, multiprocessing

I have a function called `connection` which connects to the SQL databases. It can be simplified as:

```
import psycopg2 as pg
def connection():
    _conn_DB = pg.connect(dbname="h2", user="h2naya", host=h2_IP, password=DB_PW)
    _conn_DB.set_client_encoding('UTF8')
    _conn_ML = pg.connect(dbname="postgres", user="h2naya", host="localhost", password=ML_PW)
    _conn_ML.set_client_encoding('UTF8')
    return {"db": _conn_DB, "ml": _conn_ML}
```

Now I am trying to get data within a 7-day period starting from a specified date, so I create another function:

```
import pandas as pd
conns = connection()
def get_latest_7d(date_string):
    with conns["db"] as conn:
        # date_string is formatted in my_sql in the real life
        fasting_bg_latest_7d = pd.read_sql(my_sql, conn)
        return fasting_bg_latest_7d
```

Now I can map `get_latest_7d` with a list of date strings, e.g. `map(get_latest_7d, ["2018-07-01", "2018-07-02", "2018-07-03"])`. It works.

As the list of date strings is really long, I'd like tool use `multiprocessing.Pool.map` to accelerate the procedure. However, the codes below give me *InterfaceError: connection already closed*:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
with Pool() as p:
    results = p.map(get_latest_7d, ["2018-07-01", "2018-07-02", "2018-07-03"])
```

I tried different ways and found the only working one is moving the line `conns = connection()` **inside** `get_latest_7d`, and **not** closing the connections before returning the data frame. By saying "closing the connections" I mean:

```
for conn_val in conns.values():
    conn_val.close()
```

It seems that I need to create connections for each process, and I am not allowed to close the connections before the process ends. I am curious about:

1. Why can't the connection be shared across the processes?
2. Why does closing a connection in one process affect other processes?
3. Is there any better practice for my purpose?

PS: It seems to [be recommended to build connections in each process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40482555/6666231) but I am not sure that I fully understand.

Comment: Because subprocesses *do not share state*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks. But if that's the case, why can't I close connections before exiting the function `get_latest_7d` since they do not share state?

Comment: I suspect this might be a side-effect of the pickling/unpickling. The connections copied to the subprocess become closed. Again, only a guess